# Expected to have been called with T23:59:59.999Z but the actual calls were T12:59:59.999Z

Tags: angular, jasmine, momentjs

I am using *Angular 4+* with *Moment 2.18.1*

Using `moment().endOf('day')` returns `2018-03-06T23:59:59.999Z` in the Angular application code whereas it returns `2018-03-06T12:59:59.999Z` in the jasmine tests (as of today).

I am using the following function to format the dates

```ts
private getISODate(date: any) {
    return moment(date).utc().add(date.utcOffset(), 'm').toISOString();
}
```

How do I get my tests to pass?

Comment: And this is with the Angular code and Jasmine code both running on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

I had `date.utcOffset()` in the code and `date.utcOffset` in the tests. Instead of flagging an error it gave me these different results. Javascript is weird!